# filter the first two units in panels

Tags: filter, panel, survey

i have a survered data and want to filter the oldest brothers in all families with R.

the data is organized as follows,

| familyid | ind_id | wave | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 10101 | 2022 | 32 |
| 101 | 10101 | 2023 | 33 |
| 102 | 10101 | 2021 | 41 |
| 102 | 10102 | 2021 | 35 |
| 103 | 10301 | 2021 | 56 |
| 103 | 10301 | 2022 | 57 |
| 103 | 10302 | 2022 | 44 |
| 103 | 10302 | 2023 | 45 |
| 103 | 10303 | 2022 | 46 |
| 103 | 10303 | 2023 | 47 |

any help is appreciated.